# Openshift scaling when using EBS

Tags: openshift

How does OpenShift scale when using EBS for persistent storage? How does OpenShift map users to EBS volumes? Because its infeasible to allocate 1 ebs volume to each user, how does openshift handle this in the backend using kubernetes?

Comment: If your question is related to OpenShift Online, and the restriction of only being allowed 1 persistent volume, this is *not* a platform limitation, as Kubernetes can happily allow many persistent volumes for the same user. This is a restriction of the *free* plan, and is not a limitation in [Pro](https://manage.openshift.com).

Answer (score 0):

EBS volumes can only be mounted on a single node in a cluster at a time. This means you cannot scale an application that uses one beyond 1 replica. Further, an application using an EBS volume cannot use 'Rolling' deployment strategy as that would require there to be 2 replicas when the new deployment is occurring. The deployment strategy therefore needs to be set to 'Recreate'.

Subject to those restrictions on your deployed application which has claimed a volume of type EBS, there is no problems with using EBS volumes as an underlying storage type. Kubernetes will quite happily map the volume into the pod for your application. If that pod dies and gets started on a different node, Kubernetes will then mount the volume in the pod on the new node instead, such that your storage follows the application.

If you give up a volume claim, its contents are wiped and it is returned to the pool of available volumes. A subsequent claim by you or a different user can then get that volume and it would be applied to the pod for the new application.

This is all handled and works no problems. It is a bit hard to understand what you are asking, but hopefully this gives you a better picture.